# Handle http exceptions with messages

Tags: breeze

My server returns a 403 when the user does not have permission:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 41
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 03:44:47 GMT

You do not have the necessary permission.
```

I get the following error from breeze:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y "

From here:

```
function extractErrors(XHR) {
    if (!XHR.responseText) return null;
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
    return responseObj && responseObj.EntityErrors;
}
```

Is this an error?

Comment: What version of Breeze? The latest is 1.4.2.

Comment: Also, can you show your fail logic?

Comment: It's the latest version. This seems to be a breaking change. We started getting this error after the upgrade. It worked fine before. The fail code does not execute because the parse error is thrown before the fail code is executed. It does expect the error to be passed into the fail method. 
.fail(error) { ...}

Comment: We have worked around this issue by changing the body of the response to JSON:  {"message":"The message."}